# Gitlab CI/CD integración continua sin docker

Tags: servidor, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Estoy haciendo unas practicas con gitlab CI/CD para configurar integración continua de un proyecto en un servidor Unix vía SSH sin docker.

1/ Utilizo gitlab.com

2/ He configurado el archivo .gitlab-ci.yml (doy por hecho que esta mal)

```
image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8

variables:
    EB_APP_JAR_NAME: "xxx-xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

myapplication_build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - mvn package -B -Dmaven.test.skip
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - target/$EB_APP_JAR_NAME

myapplication_deploy:
    only:
        - master
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - mvn package
        - mv target/*.jar app.jar
        - ssh xxx-xxx@xxxx.xxxxx.xxx -p 25 'sudo service xxxx-xxxx stop'
        - scp -P 25 app.jar xxxx-xxxx@xxxx.xxxxx.xxx:/home/xxxx-xxxx
        - ssh xxx-xxx@xxxx.xxxxx.xxx -p 25 'sudo service xxxx-xxxx start'
```

3/ He instalado un runner ([Como se indica aquí](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html)) y registrado como executor ssh ([Como se indica aquí](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html)) en el servidor en el que quiero hacer el deploy, el cual puedo ver como activo en gitlab settings/ci_cd/runners

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4/ Al hacer un commit sobre master el pepeline se lanzan y veo cada los dos jobs que están declarados en .gitlab-ci.yml.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no entiendo y por lo tanto no se como configurar stage deploy en .gitlab-ci.yml para que trabaje con el runner y se despliegue la aplicación en el servidor.

¿Las instrucciones que se indican script: son ejecutadas por el runner en el servidor?

¿Que instrucciones o tipo de comandos deberían estar en script: para que se puedas desplegar la aplicación de una forma sencilla sin docker?

Estoy bastante pedido en este punto, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Un saludo.

Comment: Dame 10 min que te contesto

Comment: Hola @smark182 . ¿Has podido hacer o mirar algo?

Comment: Hola @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz aun no he podido ponerme con ello, esta tarde a la vuelta del trabajo. Gracias

Comment: maven tiene su propia fase para eso, al respecto revisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412519/run-remote-command-via-ssh-using-maven3 y https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Las instrucciones que se indican script: son ejecutadas por el runner
>   en el servidor?

La imagen que estás utilizando, es una imagen Docker de maven con jdk -> `image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8` El runner que has instalado en tu servidor (runner SSH) es el encargado de ejecutar los procesos que indicas en gitlab-ci.yml (descarga el código inicialmente - controlado con el parámetro [GIT_STATEGY](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy)) - Eso significa que tienes una imagen docker, corriendo en un executor ssh.

Si quieres eliminar docker, en primer lugar, eliminaría la imagen que tienes en la cabecera. A partir de ahí y si el runner que tienes activado para ese proyecto es un runner activado como `Shell`, tendrás una sesión ssh que ejecuta el usuario del gitlab-runner que has ejecutado.

Ähí, con el maven instalado en el propio runner ssh, tienes que hacer el package y el deploy.

Cada uno de los jobs, tiene una rama asociada, en este caso, el deploy lo estás haciendo sólo en la rama master.

> ¿Que instrucciones o tipo de comandos deberían estar en script: para
>   que se puedas desplegar la aplicación de una forma sencilla sin
>   docker?

Hay plugins de deploy como [el de apache](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/), y puedes también hacer los deploy de forma manual. La mayoría de plugins de apache etc son sencillos de configurar. Sólo tienes que configurar los pom de los módulos con su `<distributionmanagement>` etc.

> Nota: Ejecutando `mvn deploy:deploy`, sólo haces el deploy, si haces
>   mvn deploy hace más funciones / compilar etc.

En Maven, sigues un ciclo estándar. Al llamar a Deploy, estás haciendo el deploy,  El [`deploy mojo` de gitlab](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) realmente puede desplegar Jars, o desplegar a repositorios o servidores. Todo depende de dónde quieras desplegar exactamente.

Te paso un gitlab-ci.yml bastante curradito, con pruebas de sonarqube si lo tuvieras, y con envoltura para código C++ (el buildwrapper, etc. Se lo puedes quitar y limpiar un poco a tu antojo, pero espero que te hagas idea). PD: mis módulos tienen el distributionmanagement en el pom.xml donde indico el server al que subo todo.

```
stages:
  - package
  - QualityGate
  - quality
  - deploy

before_script:
  ## clean the working directory
  - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx32048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m";

package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir bw_output mvn clean package -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}

objetivo_de_calidad:
  stage: QualityGate
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  only:
    - /V-/  
  script:
    - mvn --batch-mode sonar:sonar -Dsonar.cfamily.threads=64 -Dsonar.gitlab.all_issues=true -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output -Dsonar.branch.name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.gitlab.max_critical_issues_gate=${MAX_CRITICAL:=-1} -Dsonar.gitlab.max_blocker_issues_gate=${MAX_BLOCKER:=-1}  -Dsonar.gitlab.max_major_issues_gate=${MAX_MAJOR:=-1} -Dsonar.gitlab.max_info_issues_gate=${MAX_INFO:=-1}  -Dsonar.gitlab.max_minor_issues_gate=${MAX_MINOR:=-1}  -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.password=${SONAR_PASSWORD} -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL}  -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_PATH -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.json_mode=CODECLIMATE  -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME   -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}
  artifacts:
    paths: [codeclimate.json]

chequeo_nuevos_errores:
  stage: QualityGate
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  except:
    - /desarrollo/
    - /master/
    - /V-/
  script:
    - mvn --batch-mode sonar:sonar -Dsonar.cfamily.threads=64 -Dsonar.gitlab.failure_notification_mode="commit-status" -Dsonar.gitlab.all_issues=false -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview  -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output -Dsonar.branch.name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.gitlab.max_critical_issues_gate=0 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_blocker_issues_gate=0 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_major_issues_gate=0 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_info_issues_gate=0 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_minor_issues_gate=0 -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.password=${SONAR_PASSWORD} -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL}  -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_PATH -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.json_mode=CODECLIMATE  -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME   -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}
  artifacts:
    paths: [codeclimate.json]

estado_calidad_master:
  stage: QualityGate
  only:
    - master
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - mvn --batch-mode sonar:sonar -Dsonar.cfamily.threads=64 -Dsonar.gitlab.all_issues=true -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output -Dsonar.branch.name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.gitlab.max_critical_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_blocker_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_major_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_info_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_minor_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.password=${SONAR_PASSWORD} -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL}  -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_PATH -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.json_mode=CODECLIMATE  -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME   -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}
  artifacts:
    paths: [codeclimate.json]

estado_calidad_desarrollo:
  stage: QualityGate
  only:
    - desarrollo
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - mvn --batch-mode sonar:sonar -Dsonar.cfamily.threads=64 -Dsonar.gitlab.all_issues=true -Dsonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output  -Dsonar.branch.name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  -Dsonar.gitlab.max_critical_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_blocker_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_major_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_info_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.gitlab.max_minor_issues_gate=-1 -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.password=${SONAR_PASSWORD} -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT} -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL}  -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_PATH -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.json_mode=CODECLIMATE  -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}
  artifacts:
    paths: [codeclimate.json]

gitlab_code_quality:
  stage: quality
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo ok
  artifacts:
    paths: [codeclimate.json]


Install_Master_BBDD:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: master
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  when: manual
  only:
    variables:
      - $UPDATE_DATABASE == 'true'
    refs:
      - master
  script:
    - ./DataBase/InstalarBD.sh 1

wildfly_master_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  environment:
    name: master
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to wildfly" 
    - mvn -T 64 wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly.hostname=${MASTER_WILDFLY_HOSTNAME} -Dwildfly.username=${MASTER_WILDFLY_USERNAME} -Dwildfly.password=${MASTER_WILDFLY_PASSWORD} -Dartifactory.ip=${ARTIFACTORY_IP} -Dartifactory.port=${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}

Artifactory_master_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: master
  when: manual
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to Artifactory"
    - mvn -T 64 -P master


master_properties_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: master
  when: manual
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploying properties to master"
    - scp -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./Properties/*WEB*  gitlabuser@Test-WEB:/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/BillingWEB/configuration
    - scp -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./Properties/*WS*  gitlabuser@Test-WS:/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/BillingWS/configuration
    - scp -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./Properties/*EJB*  gitlabuser@Test-EJB:/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/BillingEJB/configuration
    - scp -r ~/.ssh/prueba ./Resources/*  gitlabuser@Test-EJB:/opt/wildfly/domain/servers/BillingEJB/resources


master_binary_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: master
  when: manual
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - scp -r -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./lib/*so  gitlabuser@Test-Backend:$BILLING_LIB_PATH
    - scp -r -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./bin/* gitlabuser@Test-Backend:$BILLING_BIN_PATH
    - scp -r -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./cfg/* gitlabuser@Test-Backend:$BILLING_CFG_PATH
    - scp -r -i ~/.ssh/prueba ./img/* gitlabuser@Test-Backend:$BILLING_IMG_PATH
```

---

**EDIT: Preguntas y respuestas al usuario**

**En este momento no quiero hacer el deploy con docker así que fuera docker Ok – smark182 el 7 nov. a las 23:08**

> Exacto, de este modo, lo que tienes es un runner `ssh`. Es decir, una
>   sesión SSH allí donde esté el runner instalado.

**El runner que tengo instalado en el servidor esta activado como shell Ok. – smark182 el 7 nov. a las 23:11**

> Exacto, Shell (ahora puedes elegir la shell que quieras - Bash.. etc). Las
>   propiedades de las sesión, serán las del usuario que utiliza el runner
>   (suele ser gitlab-runner p. ej.)

**¿Entonces el usuario que se crea después de instalar el runner en el servidor es el que ejecuta los comandos que se definen en .gitlab-ci.yml? Entiendo entonces que se le pasan los script al runner y los ejecuta en el servidor. – smark182 el 7 nov. a las 23:11**

> Exacto, la idea es separar la máquina de gitlab, de la máquina del
>   runner (Virtualizando, incluso en una misma máquina física es fácil).
>   De este modo, evitas que haya cualquier problema en la máquina de
>   gitlab producido por un runner que ejecute cualquier comando tipo `rm
>   -rf /${Variable_no_encontrada}*` con permisos **root**

**¿Como que maven instalado en el runner? ¿Como se instala mvn en el runner? ¿Te refieres a que los comandos mvn que se definan en script: serán ejecutados por el runner en el servidor? – smark182 el 7 nov. a las 23:12**

> Maven se puede instalar en el servidor linux, para el usuario que
>   ejecuta el runner. Es decir, para el `gitlab-runner`. De este modo, en
>   su directorio `$HOME/.mvn` tendrás su configuración propia de usuario.

**¿Ademas del runnig en el servidor es necesario configurar el pom con un plugin de apache? Pensé que el el runnig podría descargar la rama master y hacer el doploy con los comandos que se le indique en script (mvn clean, mvn package, mvn deploy...) de .gitlab-ci.yml ¿De no ser así podrías pasarme una ejemplo de pom? – smark182 el 7 nov. a las 23:13**

> Normalmente, en el `pom.xml` tienes que añadir el
>   `<distributionManagement>` , de todos modos, no sé si en el plugin de
>   Apache, se pide de este mismo modo. No sé qué servidor tienes. ¿Es
>   apache? ¿Qué quieres instalar?

**Puff :) .gitlab-ci.yml entiendo mas o menos las instrucciones el problema que tengo es que no comprendo el ultimo paso cuando se tiene que hacer el deploy en el servidor. No tengo claro si la responsabilidad de descargar el código de la rama master y hacer el deploy, es del runner o del plugin de apache () – smark182 el 7 nov. a las 23:13**

> El proceso y/o cadena de procesos que levanta el gitlab-runner, se llama pipeline. Cada pipeline, ejecuta una serie de pasos o `stages`, que configuras en el gitlab-ci.yml. 
>   Despues, cada uno de los jobs, se asocia a uno de los `stages`. De este modo, desde tu `gitlab-runner - shell` vas a ejecutar una serie de acciones Maven.
>   El tema es que el gitlab-runner necesita descargar el código antes de tiempo. Para esto, gitlab, tiene lo que se llama la `GIT_STRATEGY`. Si pones `GIT_STRATEGY: none` ahí, no se clonará el repositorio. De este modo, lo importante es hacer un `GIT_STRATEGY: clone` en algún momento. 
>   Normalmente con el mismo `mvn clean`. Por defecto, esta es la estrategia de gitlab, por lo que si evitar ponerlo, como en el método `package`, automáticamente, copiará el repositorio en la rama que quieres compilar, y realizará en él las acciones `mvn` que le pidas. Gitlab tiene [variables internas que puedes utilizar también para trabajar](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)

Comment: Hola Alejandro.

Comment: que tal, pudiste probar?

Comment: Estoy con ello ahora mismo

Comment: En este momento no quiero hacer el deploy con docker así que fuera docker Ok

Comment: El runner que tengo instalado en el servidor esta activado como shell Ok.

Comment: ¿Entonces el usuario que se crea después de instalar el runner en el servidor es el que ejecuta los comandos que se definen en .gitlab-ci.yml?  

Entiendo entonces que se le pasan los script al runner y los ejecuta en el servidor.

Comment: ¿Como que maven instalado en el runner? ¿Como se instala mvn en el runner? ¿Te refieres a que los comandos mvn que se definan en script: serán ejecutados por el runner en el servidor?

Comment: ¿Ademas del runnig en el servidor es necesario configurar el pom con un plugin de apache?  

Pensé que el el runnig podría descargar la rama master y hacer el doploy con los comandos que se le indique en script (mvn clean, mvn package, mvn deploy...) de .gitlab-ci.yml ¿De no ser así podrías pasarme una ejemplo de pom?

Comment: Puff :) .gitlab-ci.yml entiendo mas o menos las instrucciones el problema que tengo es que no comprendo el ultimo paso cuando se tiene que hacer el deploy en el servidor.  

No tengo claro si la responsabilidad de descargar el código de la rama master y hacer el deploy, es del runner o del plugin de apache (<distributionmanagement>)

Comment: Como podrás comprobar tengo una laguna importante.  

Espero que me puedas ayudar a aclararme.  

Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Luego te cuento

Comment: Ok Alejandro, Gracias

Comment: No te olvides de mi :)

Comment: Q va, ayer me fue imposible tío, deja que me sentare hoy por la mañana en el pc y te lo miro bien, que xonnel móvil es un poco de locos!!

Comment: A ver, voy por orden . Escribo editando la respuesta